# Android unit test Robolectric Maven : The method buildActivity(Class<MyActivity>) is undefined for the type Robolectric

Tags: android, maven, robolectric, android-testing

I am trying to creat some tests for my android application in Maven/Eclipse with Roboelectric.

I have an error in the method buildActivity() from the Robolectric class:

```
The method buildActivity(Class<MyActivity>) is undefined for the type Robolectric
```

This is how I am calling it :

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(StartActivity.class).create()
            .get();
}
```

And this is my dependency in POM.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.robolectric</groupId>
        <artifactId>robolectric</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-alpha-2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Every suggestion is welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Robolectric 2.2? Do you get the same error when you run using the mvn command line tool?

Comment: yes , it is exactly the same.

Comment: Then this isn't an issue with Eclipse, but more generally with Maven + Robolectric