# The method buildActivity(Class<MainActivity>) is undefined for the type Robolectric

Tags: android, eclipse, robolectric

i am getting  error`The method buildActivity(Class<ActivityMain>) is undefined for the type Robolectric` while testing with `robolectric` while using this method like

```
activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();

I am using the given jars in my lib folder
fest-android-1.0.8.jar
fest-assert-core-2.0M10.jar
fest-util-1.1.6.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
junit-4.11-sources.jar
junit-4.11.jar
mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
robolectric-2.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar
robolectric-with-dependencies.jar
```

However this question was asked previously but there was no answer posted for this question.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089050/android-unit-test-robolectric-maven-the-method-buildactivityclassmyactivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i am using `import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.Robolectric`  so it was conflicting with `import org.robolectric.Robolectric;` so i removed `import com.xtremelabs.robolectric.Robolectric`  with `import org.robolectric.Robolectric;` now its working.cheeers